# How come android is better than maemo?

Tags: android

hi
i hope you can enlighten me fellows.
im a developer trying to migrate to android from nokia community Maemo & Symbian.

1.Android doesnt run Linux Software ? :S :S
It was so easy back in maemo.all you need to was install proper dependencies and some small modifications.

2.There is even no Linux Softwares ported to android i dunno by some skillful programmers :S whyyy people why

3.Why it seems so hard install other Linux OS's onto Android devices :S ?
it's a linux based Opensource OS like in maemo.it must be so easy.it was as easy as one click on maemo :S

4.Why they say android is not capable enough to run Python apps :S ?
even 5-6 year old symbian phones run python apps smoothly for example : 6600.

5.Every android device has its own different mods?
i mean is it possible to use nexus one's usb host driver hack&tutorial on another usb host(hackable :D ) capable android device.

i got this doubts and hesitations in my mind 
i just wanna know about these before buying an expensive android device.

Comment: Your questions appear a tad leading and entering troll territory. I'd suggest rewriting them in a more neutral tone. But, to answer the question AFAIK, isn't Symbian only have a year left on its life before Nokia fully switches to Winodws7?

Comment: This question seems to be argumentative.  The fact is that Android runs C++ and Java code, that is what it is limited to, but it has capabilities that Maemo doesn't have.

Comment: Nokia really dropped the ball with Maemo. Maemo 5 was ahead of Android (2.0 at the time?) when it first came out: adobe flash, video calling, real multi-tasking. Then Nokia proceeded to abandon Maemo to pursue MeeGo, which they now gave up on, instead of capitalizing on Maemo's strengths.

Comment: @DA i agree with that i know Symbian is already dead that's why im trying to migrate to Android but im trying to find some amazing features

Comment: This is not about programming. This is about comparing mobile OS. Off-topic here.

Comment: no it's about programming im going to start studying for android development but im trying to find out will it worth it

Comment: @JamesBlack are there similar high-level api's for c++ like the ones in java?

Comment: Not a relevant question to ask in programming forum. Also, negativity reflected in the questions asked.

Comment: "trying to find some amazing features" well, that's purely subjective, so definitely not a question that belongs in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct Forum -- but here goes.

Android phones are more functional, easier to use, and generally plain nicer than Symbian or Meamo phones.

Its all about the finished product and the end user experience. Both iPhone and Android are nice to use. Nokia phones are not.

Nokia had a head start in this area when they bought Symbian, before the iPhone came out the Symbian organizer had the best user interface of any hand held device. Things went downhill almost immediately after the Nokia purchase.

This may sound opinionated (and all End User Experience issues are in the end a matter of opinion!). But there is an important software principle here:-

**Understanding and fulfilling your end users requirements is more important than the technology used**

Comment: this was kind of an answer i was looking for :) thanks :)

Comment: It's definitely an opinion, and limited to subjective opinion given the amount of space we have, but I'd agree and I think most UX folks would agree that we could come up with a long list of OBJECTIVE UX failings of the Nokia platform overall. I have to test mobile web sites daily on all sorts of devices and Nokias are always the thorn in my side.

Answer (score 5):

Android starts with A, Maemo starts with M.  A comes before M, so Android is better.  Isn't this obvious?